# Comparing ALL settings between two separate powershell windows in the ISE?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

TL;DR - I have a window in the ISE where I somehow got my script to work.  If I start a new window (aka session?) in the ISE and copy/paste the code, the script fails. I'm trying to figure out what is different between the sessions so that I can get it to reliably work. I'm hoping there's some setting or something that I set in one that's not in the other, but I'm clearing variables between runs (see below) so I just don't know.

Long version:

I have a Powershell SMO/SQLServer script that works in one window in the ISE that uses ScriptTransfer(), which is a module inside the SQLServer module.

When I create a new window (aka new session) and copy/paste the code and run it against one particular server/database, the scripttransfer fails.  I have no idea how I managed to get it working, but I want to duplicate that.  The code works on most of my databases, but fails on one particular one, and there's no easy way to figure out what's going wrong inside that module, and the error message I get back is:

```
Exception calling "ScriptTransfer" with "0" argument(s): "Script transfer failed. "
At line:68 char:1
+ $transfer.ScriptTransfer()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException
```

Here's the code.  It works on most databases, but I've got one DB that's causing these errors.  Including it here just to be complete.

```
Remove-Variable -Name * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  #allows us to run repeatedly in same session for testing.

import-module sqlserver #yes, necessary, at least so that you know if the scripttransfer fails, you need to get a newer version.


$servername = "mydb"
$databasename = "myserver" 
$workingdirectory ="c:\temp\backup" 

"servername is $servername"
"databasename is $databasename"
"uploadtos3 is $uploadtoS3"
"accesskey is $accesskey"
"secretkey is $secretkey"
"workingdirectory is $workingdirectory"
"bucketname is $bucketname"
"regionname is $regionname"
"s3path is $s3path"

####################
# 0 - Declarations #
####################
$credentials = set-awscredentials -accesskey $accesskey -secretkey $secretkey
$sql_server = $servername
$DBToScript = $databasename 
$path = $workingdirectory         #I'd use a UNC path here

################################
# 1 - Scripting out the CREATE #
################################
$SMOServer = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList "$sql_server"
$db = $SMOServer.Databases[$DBToScript]
$create_database = $db.Script() -replace("\d+KB","100mb") -replace("\d+mb","100mb") -replace("\d+GB","100mb")
#while I couldn't get it to script out the GO terminators (ScriptBatchTerminator), it doesn't need it for the create.
$create_database |Out-File "$path\$($dbtoscript)_db_create.sql" -Force -Encoding ascii -Append 
#using out-file since I can't figure out which setting uses filename.

#####################################
# 2 - Scripting out all the objects #
#####################################
#using transfer as it seems more straightforward.

$transfer = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer #-ArgumentList $db
$transfer.Database = $db
$transfer.CopyAllObjects = $true
$transfer.CopySchema = $true
$transfer.CopyAllSchemas= $true
$transfer.Options.Indexes = $true
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.filename = "$path\$($dbtoscript)_db_objects.sql"
$transfer.Options.ExtendedProperties= $true # yes, we want these
$transfer.Options.DRIAll= $true # and all the constraints 
$transfer.Options.Indexes= $true # Yup, these would be nice
$transfer.Options.Triggers= $true # This should be included when scripting a database
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.IncludeHeaders = $false #pshaw
$transfer.Options.ToFileOnly = $true #no need of string output as well
$transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = $false # not necessary but it means the script can be more versatile

"test"
# This first ScriptTransfer MUST stay! Otherwise it leaves out the WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER on CLR SPs
$transfer.ScriptTransfer() |out-null
$transfer.ScriptTransfer()
```

Comment: After the script fails, try `$Error | select *`. That should show the stack trace, maybe there is better an error message down the stack. Also, if some objects already exist, you might get this error, as per [dba.stackexchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122149).

Comment: Okay, that helped quite a bit.  THANKS!  "Cannot create Index without specifying one or more columns."  Now to figure that one out. :D